# Async method always returning true

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am implementing a login functionality with firebase and React Native. The `handleLogin` method is always returning `succeed()`. If I remove the `success()`, I get :

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result2.failed')]

```
export default async function login(credentials) {
    let result2= succeed();
    result2 = await handleLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    if(result2.failed()){
       return fail({password: "Login failed"});
    }
    else{          
       return succeed();
    } 
}

const handleLogin = async(email,password) => {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) { 
         console.log(error); 
         return fail("failed");
     })

     return succeed(); // or fail() in which case method always returns fail()
```

I have also tried using `.then()` but I keep getting object undefined error if I don't return `succeed()` or `fail()` in the end of `handleLogin()`:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(){return succeed();})
    .catch(function(error) { 
        console.log("we fail"+error); 
        return fail("failed");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue of the firebase. Similar thing happened to me on angular code.

Comment: Any reference link?

Comment: Do not rely on its state. May be try something else to get you're requirement. Like user logs in by some other method you try to check if success or false. Unless you dig into nodemofules of firebase as in why it always returns true.

Comment: I mean the known issue reference link? A GitHub issue? or something similar?

Comment: solved it by returning auth.signInWithEmail...

Comment: @shardul Can you post an answer saying what you changed, and why that solved the problem? Self-answers are encouraged on Stack Overflow, as your learnings may be useful to other developers with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Hey ikhvjs don't have a git link we had faced similar issue locally ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a return statement:

```
return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){return succeed();}).catch(function(error) { return fail("Login Attempt Failed\n"+error);})
```